# Why isn't this form displaying as it's input?

Tags: php, html, css

When someone inputs notes on this form it isn't displaying as it's written.

It should display as:

Notes: Please go to 34th Floor Reception Desk.
 
       Doors do not open until 8:00 am

Instead, it is displaying as:

Notes: Please go to 34th Floor Reception Desk. Doors do not open until 8:00 am

Here is the code for that section:

```
<td valign="top">
        <?php
        $location = $c->firm.'<br />'.
                    $c->address.'<br />'.
                    $c->location_city;
        echo $location ?>
        <?php if($c->notes):?>
        <br/><br/>
        Notes: <?=$c->notes?>
        <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

I'm not very experienced in PHP, and semi-experienced in HTML.  I'm not sure what I would need to do to have it use the line breaks a user inserts to the field.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also don't forget to always, always, always use `htmlspecialchars()` on everything you `echo` to an HTML page *unless* it is meant to be output as HTML (rather than plain text). For example, if my "note" was `I love <table> tags!` you wouldn't want it to actually open a table element.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php